# Replacing XML DataIsland Files in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xml

The app I am working on, currently uses XML dataisland files to retrieve the dropdown data. Below is the code that defines the file.

```
    <xml id="DefaultDataIslands" src="../XMLData/DataIslands-<%=((User.Identity).Database)%>.xml">
    </xml>
```

Below is an example code that uses these XML dataislands.

```
var oDataIsland = document.getElementById("DefaultDataIslands");
var oXmlNodes = oDataIsland.XMLDocument.selectNodes("XMLDataIslands/DataIsland[@ID='DIMRGroup']/Option");
```

**This oDataIsland line is used about 4k times total in the application. The application itself is intranet, so, I can even ask the users to download the xml files directly. Whole point is to keep the changes required to minimum, while removing all traces of XML tags. I want to make sure that application works on Chrome once this thing is completed.**

I checked the link from mozilla regarding the dataislands here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_XML_Data_Islands_in_Mozilla

Below is the code based on that mozilla link.

```
    var doc = document.getElementById(strDataSource).contentDocument;
    var mainNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("DataIsland");
    var oXmlNodes;
    var strOptions = "";
    //finds the selected node based on the id, and gets the options for that id
    for (i = 0; i < mainNode.length; i++) {

        if (mainNode[i].getAttributeNode("ID").nodeValue == strDataMember) {
            oXmlNodes = mainNode[i].getElementsByTagName("Option");
        }
    }
```

This code reads the data properly, works perfectly in IE (10 with standards mode, no quirks), was easy enough change to do in the full solution.

**Only problem is, `document.getElementById(strDataSource).contentDocument;` line fails in Chrome. This is the same line as what was mentioned in Mozilla's documentation. But somehow `contentDocument` property is undefined on chrome.**

So, I need some other suggestion on how to get this fixed. I tried other methods, using HTTPRequest (too many request per page), using JSON (requires changing existing methods completely), using backend to process XML instead of doing it client side (requires architectural changes). Till now, all these ideas failed.

Is there any other method that I can use? Or should I fix the `contentDocument` issue?

Comment: you can replace (mostly) the `selectNodes`  interface with a `document.evaluate` command, which also works on ajax documents (the response of xml resources). if you really want to make it wait, change the 3rd argument of open() to `false`, but that's not advisable.

Comment: That selectNodes line is repeated in about 4k places. It will be a monumental task to replace them all. That's why trying to keep that working as is, and just finding a better method to get XML. One of my friend suggested going the JSON route. So, trying to use that to test.

Comment: since not many libs use those old-school interfaces, you can probably safely get away with monkey-patching a `.selectNodes()` method that is defined by a function that more or less wraps `document.evaluate`, so that your existing code will work without modification. you can probably just define an `XMLDocument` shell object on #DefaultDataIslands that only contains the aforementioned selectNodes() method... `DefaultDataIslands.XMLDocument={selectNodes: function fnThatUsesEvaluate(){...} }`

Comment: I know I can do that. But, that monkeypatching won't help with the server requests for every single dropdown. Instead of reading from xml, if I use httprequest, my server will break down. I am sure, you understand that is a bit of a problem. So, I am thinking of forgetting XMLHttpRequest method completely, and going a different route.

Comment: oh, you just need to re-fetch the xml whenever you think it might have changed. if that's never or nightly, then you can fetch it once and fake the data island from the same response over and over, which will be very fast.

Comment: How do I fake the data island? BTW, I am currently using a new method to get the files. Check the updated question.

Comment: Hard to read this question as you brainstorm a little. From what I gather the main issue is: *I want to remove this xml tag* from an xml file. I have a perfect answer for you then. If this is not the need and you require JS/ASP frameworks, I'll carry on.

Comment: Sorry, I will update the question. I thought, it will be easy for people to know what I have already tried. As for the problem, I want to remove the xml tag from aspx file, but want to keep the code rework to minimum.

Answer (score 0):

To allow `contentDocument` in Chrome, you will have to use `--allow-file-access-from-files`. Following are the steps for doing so:

1. Get the url of your Chrome Installation path to your chrome
   installation e.g
   C:\Users-your-user-name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application>
2. Launch the Google Chrome browser from the command line window with
   the additional argument ‘–allow-file-access-from-files’. E.g ‘path
   to your chrome installation\chrome.exe
   --allow-file-access-from-files’
3. Temporary method you can use each time you are testing

   - Copy the existing chrome launcher
   - Do as above and save it with a new name e.g chrome - testing
   - Alternatively, you can simply create a new launcher with the above and use it to start chrome.

[Source](http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/windows.html)

Comment: Do I have to do this for each user? Say, I am running it on my pc, and using the application hosted on a friend's pc. In that case, do I need to enable it on my pc too? Because that would mean changing this setting on hundred devices which use this.

Comment: @jitendragarg did this fix your issue?

Comment: It does fix the issue, although, I don't think I can do it on every pc. I am still looking for a different solution that works without requiring compromises on security. So, if you find any other trick, do let me know.