# contentDocument property is undefined for xml document

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use Mozilla's documentation about removing xml dataislands. The code from the same is failing for weird reasons. Here is the link. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_XML_Data_Islands_in_Mozilla

Exact code

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>XML Data Block Demo</title>
<script>
function runDemo() {
var doc = document.getElementById("purchase-order").contentDocument;
var lineItems = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://example.mozilla.org/PurchaseOrderML", "lineItem");
var firstPrice = lineItems[0].getElementsByTagNameNS("http://example.mozilla.org/PurchaseOrderML", "price")[0].textContent;
document.getElementById("output-box").textContent = "The purchase order contains " + lineItems.length + " line items. The price of the first line item is " + firstPrice + ".";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="runDemo()";>
<object id="purchase-order" data="purchase_order.xml" type="text/xml" style="display: none;"></object>
<div id="output-box">Demo did not run</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code, `var doc = document.getElementById("purchase-order").contentDocument;` line is causing the error `object does not support contentDocument property` in both Chrome and IE.

What am I possibly missing here?

Edit:

I found the issue with IE. IE does not support this property in compatibility mode. Removed the compatibility mode and it works fine now.

**But same thing still fails in Chrome. I don't think there is a compatibility mode enabled in chrome. So no idea why chrome is failing.**

Edit:
This was supposed to be in continuation of the methods I was trying to remove XML dataisland. I think, updating the old question is a better idea.

Comment: Try other way round - `var doc = document.contentDocument.getElementById("purchase-order");`

Comment: same error.  contentDocument does not exist for document either

Comment: Can you share the `html` too??

Comment: this is the exact code from the tutorial. the exact code is not working. it has html and script already. :/

Comment: Did you try reaching the site where the `xml` is been fetched? i.e http://example.mozilla.org/PurchaseOrderML

Comment: I changed it to read the xml that was on my solution. I can reach the same if I use `<xml src="purchaseorder.xml"/>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing XML DataIsland Files in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154674/replacing-xml-dataisland-files-in-asp-net)